# Rocky 8 - Apache2 Radius authentication?

Tags: apache2, radius

I've Rocky 8 (RHEL based Linux) server with already working Radius-authentication for SSH.
It's an external Radius-server (Cisco ISE).
Now I'd like to use this Radius-server also for authentication for specific internal Webpages (running Apache2). Something like .htaccess but with Radius-authentication.
I've found something with Python pyrad.
But this does not work for me, just getting "internal server error".
Has someone done this with RHEL-based Linux?
**I've now also tried with mod_auth_xradius, but now I always see the following log: "xradius: Failed to add server ':1812': (-1) : host not found".**
But of course I've configured the servers in the conf file under /etc/http/conf.d/myradius.conf
I just want the most basic solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found information here:
https://collectivenothing.blogspot.com/2013/09/using-radius-authentication-with-apache.html

The patch did not work, but when I only configure ONE radius-server it works!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).